# Programming stepper motor move a fixed step till it reach the target

Tags: motor

I have a stepper motor and try to program it like this but I kinda stuck since I'm new to Arduino. 
1. The target is set to 2048, means motor have to move 2048 steps.
2. I program the motor to run 200 steps each time, every 200 steps will stop for a sec until it reach 2048.

I've been using AccelStepper library to program my motor, I found out it is very hard for me to program like this. I'm not asking to do my homework but I dunno where to start. Just wanted to ask what method can I use to program the motor to work like this. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried modifying one of the examples provided with the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with the Blocking example provided with the library. Add the delays you need, the steps/distance you want. The following is simple but crude. It is call blocking code. It can only do the following sequence, but sometimes that is good enough.

A bit better would be to have a conditional loop to get to the final target. The loop would move 200, then delay 1 second, subtract the amount moved. Loop until you use up all the required distance. But initially I suggest to keep it simple and just make it work with inline sequences.

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>
// Define a stepper and the pins it will use
AccelStepper stepper; // Defaults to AccelStepper::FULL4WIRE (4 pins) on 2, 3, 4, 5
void setup()
{  
    stepper.setMaxSpeed(200.0);
    stepper.setAcceleration(100.0);
}
void loop()
{    
    stepper.runToNewPosition(0);
    delay(1000);
    stepper.runToNewPosition(200);
    delay(1000);
    stepper.runToNewPosition(200);
    delay(1000);
    stepper.runToNewPosition(200);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will read first. Appreciate it!